# AWK print only the lines which have dot

Tags: shell, awk

How to print only the lines which contains dot(`.`) in the 5th column and remove the colon(`:`) at the end.

I would like to avoid repeating use of awk with `|` rather would love to have do all trick's with single `awk`

**This is my command ouput with `awk`**

```
$ awk '{a[$5]++;} END{for(i in a) print a[i]"  "i}' netappev.logs
4  wafl.vol.full:
5
3  sis.changelog.full:
1  17:58:41
1  using
1  "event
21  vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition:
4  wafl.mirror.access.denied:
76  secd.authsys.lookup.failed:
7  wafl.vol.runningOutOfInodes:
```

One way to print lines which have dot(`.`) only with `grep`:

```
$ awk '{a[$5]++;} END{for(i in a) print a[i]"  "i}' netappev.logs | grep \\.
4  wafl.vol.full:
3  sis.changelog.full:
21  vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition:
4  wafl.mirror.access.denied:
76  secd.authsys.lookup.failed:
7  wafl.vol.runningOutOfInodes:
```

removing colon(`:`) using `|` with `AWK` again.

```
$ awk '{a[$5]++;} END{for(i in a) print a[i]"  "i}' netappev.logs | grep \\. | awk -F: '{print $1}'
4  wafl.vol.full
3  sis.changelog.full
21  vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition
4  wafl.mirror.access.denied
76  secd.authsys.lookup.failed
7  wafl.vol.runningOutOfInodes
```

### EDIT:

raw data as asked by @Ed Morton in the comment.

```
Last login time: 2/19/2021 17:58:41
Time                Node             Severity      Event
------------------- ---------------- ------------- ---------------------------
2/19/2021 22:32:16  ksg6007          ERROR         vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition: Broadcast domain KSGI_mgmt-38 is partitioned into 2 groups on node ksg6007. The different groups are: {a0a-38}, {e0M}. LIFs hosted on the ports in this broadcast domain may be at the risk of seeing connectivity issues.
2/19/2021 22:31:31  ksg6013          ERROR         wafl.vol.runningOutOfInodes: The file system on Volume tpv6010_ida_ipdev_workareas@vserver:577ffe3f-4d04-11e7-92cf-00a098c5e37c is using 80 percent or more of the files that can be contained on the volume.
2/19/2021 22:30:03  ksg6005          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (28274) on Vserver (tpv6009) for client with IP address (10.137.170.142).
2/19/2021 22:29:52  ksg6007          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (45509) on Vserver (tpv6011) for client with IP address (10.137.170.112).
2/19/2021 22:29:52  ksg6014          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (45509) on Vserver (tpv6011) for client with IP address (10.137.170.112).
2/19/2021 22:28:37  ksg6006          ERROR         vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition: Broadcast domain KSGI_mgmt-38 is partitioned into 2 groups on node ksg6006. The different groups are: {a0a-38}, {e0M}. LIFs hosted on the ports in this broadcast domain may be at the risk of seeing connectivity issues.
2/19/2021 22:28:01  ksg6008          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (28274) on Vserver (tpv6009) for client with IP address (10.137.170.142).
2/19/2021 22:27:15  ksg6014          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46537) on Vserver (tpv6010) for client with IP address (10.137.171.26).
2/19/2021 22:27:00  ksg6005          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (35828) on Vserver (tpvtp605) for client with IP address (165.114.117.122).
2/19/2021 22:25:49  ksg6013          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (997) on Vserver (tpv6010) for client with IP address (165.114.118.231).
2/19/2021 22:24:49  ksg6005          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (45509) on Vserver (tpv6010) for client with IP address (10.137.170.112).
2/19/2021 22:24:49  ksg6007          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (45509) on Vserver (tpv6010) for client with IP address (10.137.170.112).
2/19/2021 22:24:49  ksg6008          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (45509) on Vserver (tpv6011) for client with IP address (10.137.170.112).
2/19/2021 22:23:49  ksg6008          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46537) on Vserver (tpv6010) for client with IP address (10.137.171.26).
2/19/2021 22:23:49  ksg6013          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46537) on Vserver (tpv6010) for client with IP address (10.137.171.26).
2/19/2021 22:23:47  ksg6005          ERROR         vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition: Broadcast domain KSGI_mgmt-38 is partitioned into 2 groups on node ksg6005. The different groups are: {a0a-38}, {e0M}. LIFs hosted on the ports in this broadcast domain may be at the risk of seeing connectivity issues.
2/19/2021 22:23:35  ksg6008          ERROR         vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition: Broadcast domain KSGI_mgmt-38 is partitioned into 2 groups on node ksg6008. The different groups are: {a0a-38}, {e0M}. LIFs hosted on the ports in this broadcast domain may be at the risk of seeing connectivity issues.
2/19/2021 22:22:37  ksg6007          ALERT         wafl.vol.full: Insufficient space on volume tpv6009_scratch001@vserver:41dd0809-477f-11e7-92cf-00a098c5e37c to perform operation. 8.00KB was requested but only 1.00KB was available.
2/19/2021 22:22:35  ksg6013          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46329) on Vserver (tpv6009) for client with IP address (165.114.116.50).
2/19/2021 22:21:12  ksg6006          ERROR         wafl.mirror.access.denied: Access to SnapMirror volume 'tpv6010_da' was denied because SnapMirror initialization was not complete (exported Snapshot copy identifier '0' is invalid).
2/19/2021 22:21:04  ksg6014          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46537) on Vserver (tpv6009) for client with IP address (165.114.118.133).
2/19/2021 22:21:02  ksg6005          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46709) on Vserver (tpv6009) for client with IP address (10.137.169.63).
2/19/2021 22:21:02  ksg6005          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46329) on Vserver (tpv6011) for client with IP address (10.137.170.238).
2/19/2021 22:20:58  ksg6007          ERROR         vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition: Broadcast domain KSGI_mgmt-38 is partitioned into 2 groups on node ksg6007. The different groups are: {a0a-38}, {e0M}. LIFs hosted on the ports in this broadcast domain may be at the risk of seeing connectivity issues.
2/19/2021 22:20:02  ksg6005          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46329) on Vserver (tpv6010) for client with IP address (10.137.170.238).
2/19/2021 22:19:43  ksg6013          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (46709) on Vserver (tpv6011) for client with IP address (10.137.169.63).
2/19/2021 22:19:08  ksg6013          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (994) on Vserver (tpv6011) for client with IP address (165.114.116.101).
2/19/2021 22:19:02  ksg6008          ERROR         secd.authsys.lookup.failed: Unable to retrieve credentials for UNIX user with UID (45509) on Vserver (tpv6009) for client with IP address (10.137.170.112).
```

Comment: If you [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can best help you. See [ask].

Comment: Always try to think of and phrase your requirements in positive rather than negative terms, e.g. instead of `remove the line which do not have dot` you could say `print only the lines which have dot`. That makes for much clearer requirements, avoids double negatives creeping in, and avoids the negatives from  your requirements bleeding into your code and making that complicated too.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you very much for your inputs, i always follow your nice tricks over so, I have just edited my question, i tried to re-phrase my post syntactically however i don't have good flow in English being non-native English person.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't ask for raw data, though, I asked for a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output - the raw data you provided isn't a miminal set of input needed to demonstrate your requirements, and the expected output given that input is still missing so what you provided isn't a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following, since no samples are given so couldn't test it.

```
awk '{a[$5]++} END{for(i in a){if(i~/\./){print a[i]"  "i}}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Basically add an additional check in your attempted program's `END` block to check if variable i contains dot then only print them else don't.

To handle colons(get value before 1st colon as per shown attempts) also try following then: I could have also used substitution on variable i but in case you may need to use it further so I am going with `split` here. Split its value with `:` delimiter and print very 1st value of it. This is also not considering that colon will come always in last.

```
awk '{a[$5]++} END{for(i in a){if(i~/\./){split(i,arr,":");print a[i]"  "arr[1]}}}' Input_file
```

OR with `sub`: As per OP's comments adding it here this variant too, considering that your colon will come always in last of values.

```
awk '{a[$5]++} END{for(i in a){if(i~/\./){sub(/:$/,"",i);print a[i]"  "i}}}' Input_file
```

Comment: thank you so much , this works  but can we add to remove `:` as well?

Comment: @kulfi, Your welcome, please do try my edited code and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: thank you very much again , it work perfectly, however what is ` I could have also used substitution on variable`,  if could exhibit that as well then maybe good for future vistors as well.

Comment: @kulfi, sure I have added that solution also now, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 3):

> How i can remove the line which does not contain dot(`.`) with.
> Secondly remove the colon(`:`) from the every line as we see at the end.

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' '
{
   sub(/:$/, "", $5)
   a[$5]++
}
END {
   for (i in a)
      if (index(i, "."))
         print a[i], i
}' netappev.logs
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, can you explain a bit about `(index(i, ".")` .

Comment: `index` is function to preform string search (non-regex and faster). Here it searches first position of `.` in variable `i`. It returns position or `0` if not found

Comment: Ah thanks. I knew about this but made a typo

Answer (score 3):

this should do...

```
awk '$5~/\./ {sub(/:$/,"",$5); a[$5]++} 
     END     {for(i in a) print a[i] "  " i}' file
```

removing `:` after the counts may yield unwanted results, assume you have text: and text, they will appear as two separate lines.

If you don't like to refer to the same field multiple times, assign to a variable at the first use.

```
awk '(k=$5)~/\./ {sub(/:$/,"",k); a[k]++} 
     END         {for(k in a) print a[k] "  " k}' file
```

Comment: it will keep the reported counts the same, since there is no rescaling it should be the same.

Comment: Ah you're right, silly me, I overthought ++

Comment: Thanks Karakfa, nice one, however we are calling `$5` multiple times but elegant.

Comment: @kulfi, there is no "calling", it's a field reference but yes, multiple times. Please see the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

From the block of data you posted it seems like this might be what you're trying to do but without the associated expected output it's a guess:

```
$ awk -F'[: ]+' 'NF>7{print $7}' file | sort | uniq -c
     20 secd.authsys.lookup.failed
      5 vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition
      1 wafl.mirror.access.denied
      1 wafl.vol.full
      1 wafl.vol.runningOutOfInodes
```

or if you prefer awk only:

```
$ awk -F'[: ]+' 'NF>7{cnt[$7]++} END{for (i in cnt) print cnt[i], i}' file
1 wafl.vol.full
5 vifmgr.bcastDomainPartition
20 secd.authsys.lookup.failed
1 wafl.mirror.access.denied
1 wafl.vol.runningOutOfInodes
```

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton for getting time to provide your answer +1, as always awsome.